# How do you select multiple items from a listview and work upon them on android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In the android app that I am trying to develop.

There are some people who go together to some place and spend money together. Since when we are going in a group we make group purchases and people tend to pay for each other. Often we forget who owes and by how much.

I want to design an android app that does away with this problem. For this I take the name of all people who wish to go together say Sam, Roy and Ria.

They they purchase a list of items which I also enter. Say they purchase together Teddy, RC Car and a chocolate with prices $50, $120 and $30. Suppose Ria wanted the Teddy, Sam and Roy together wanted RC Car and all three wanted chocolates. So the amount each one should be paying is $60 for Ria ($50 + 1/3 of $30 = $60), Sam and Roy (1/2 of $120 + 1/3 of $30 = $70 each).

So to implement this what I do is for each item, I display it in the top with the names of people in a list view with check boxes in front of each individual list item. For each item I tick the list item (person) who had made purchase for the item and press next. Similarly all the items are displayed and the amount to be paid by each person is now calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem in selecting multiple list items or either on knowing which list item of activity is selected or which one is unselected .

all of these things can be easily done by creating a getter setter class with two custom field  one is string selected and one is unselected with all other getter setter objects.

then create a custom arraylist with getter setter data type like this one

```
ArrayList<MyGetterSetter> listData = new ArrayList<MyGetterSetter> ();
```

and getter setter class:

```
Class MyGetterSetter
{
   int selected , unselected ;

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(int selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public int getUnselected() {
        return unselected;
    }
    public void setUnselected(int unselected) {
        this.unselected = unselected;
    }
}
```

then set by default value of selected =0; and unselected =1;
at the time you add real time data to your getter setters  usually during json parsing or fetching data from database and inserting that to arraylist.

then set your list adapter with the custom array list you created to display views data.

```
MyGetterSetter model = listData.get(position);

if(model.getSelected==1)
{
 yourCheckbox.setSelected(true);
}
else
{
yourCheckbox.setSelected(false);
}
```

//Also set the checkbox/button click listener in adapter by this way..

```
yourCheckbox.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener
{
public void onClick(View view)
{
if(model.getSelected==1)
{
 yourCheckbox.setSelected(false);
 model.setSelected=0;
 model.setUnSelected=1;
}
else
{
yourCheckbox.setSelected(true);
model.setSelected=1;
model.setUnSelected=0;
}
}
```

then on each item click by activity list item click listener change the values of selected =1 if selected or unselected = 0 ; 
if list item is selected by user
either set selected=0 and unselected = 1; 
if unselected by user.

then right below the list attach a button on that button click loop whole the adapter data and or array-list data and check the status and position. 
if found selected=1 
then calculate the amount for that particular item with other selected list items.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setChoiceMode()` method.

```
setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```